# How do zeros outside the unit circle affect the stability of a system?

Tags: poles-zeros

I'm learning about poles and zeros of transfer functions in my signals class and we have just covered the effects of poles outside the unit circle on the pole-zero plot. Intuitively, it makes sense that a pole outside the circle would cause the system to become unstable. However, I am a bit confused about the effect of a zero outside the unit circle. I was told that zeros do not affect the stability of a system, even if they are found outside the unit circle. Is there a reason why this is true? Mathematically, how would this be different from a pole?

Comment: Do you know the influence of poles and zeros on the behavior of the system response?

Comment: I think I understand the base concepts. A zero will zero out the frequency it is located at while a pole will amplify its location frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instability refers to a situation where the output of a system **grows without bound** over time. This can happen when one or more poles lie outside the unit circle.

As you correctly observed in your question's comment section, zeros will *"zero out"* the output, so the output can never "grow" no matter where this zero is located.

Zeros inside/outside the unit circle is also an important concept, but they do not affect stability.

Comment: *"This can happen when one or more poles lie outside the unit circle."*: if you need detail on that, happy to give you some, but you said you already understood this.

Comment: No, I understand it now, thank you for your help!